# Absolute fastest method of hashing a string in PHP

Tags: php

What is the absolute fastest way to hash a string in PHP?

I have read that md5 can be relatively slow but am unsure of the alternatives.

Basically, i have a function that i need to squeeze every last bit of performance possible out of and within that function i have a string say "yada yada yada" and i need it hashed in someway so it becomes one string.

I should note that security is no issue here - i simply need a single unique string representation, as its for a cache key.

Comment: _i simply need a single unique string representation_ - FWIW, There's no such thing.

Comment: You **need** to squeeze every last bit of performance possible out of? Are you ssuurree you need to do that? What is so critical that the default hashing is too slow?

Comment: Would you please tell us why would you need performance for such thing? What is the problem you are solving, that requires hashing performance, yet makes PHP a decent tool to use?

Comment: Hashes can be calculated very quickly using the [division method](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page211.html)  - However you will need some sort of [collision handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) then as the string representation will not be unique. It depends a lot on the specific input data to be hashed (amount, variability, etc ...). Maybe you can provide some more details about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of a hash is that it's -not- fast. The faster the hash is the faster it can be cracked.

By that logic, the less secure the hash is - the faster it'll be. If you're going to favour such logic I suggest you either stop what you're doing or use encryption instead.

### In response to your update

It sounds like you may want a [`CRC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). Again it's worth mentioning that  typically the faster the check is the less combinations exist for the particular algorithm, and thus it's less likely to be a "unique representation".

The associated PHP documentation can be found here: [`hash function with crc32/crc32b`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help Martin.  So you sugges crc32 is slightly faster than md5?

Comment: It depends how often you run it.. Over millions of iterations you'll notice a difference in performance, but still on a typical machine it will be measurable in seconds.

Answer (score 3):

[Benchmarks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#89574). I seem to recall reading somewhere that this depends a lot of your version of apache and PHP, can't remember where though. I'll post if I remember :)

Comment: He also posted his benchmark test, so you can check it in your own environment.